# F5 no longer refreshes browser, but opens browser history in all browsers

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, browser, synergy

Weird issue crept up a few days ago.  All of the sudden, when I hit F5 to refresh a page, it opens the browser history on all browsers.  Testing it out, I found that F9 now refreshes my browser page.  I am not sure what I did to change this but I have tried uninstalling the keyboard, messing with the accessibility settings, etc.

Has anyone ever seen this happen?  If so, what is the fix?  It is driving me crazy as I keep forgetting F9 is my refresh now.

EDIT: One more note that might be of importance.  I am using a software KVM (Synergy) for keyboard and mouse between desktop and laptop.

Comment: what OS are you using? and which browsers?

Comment: Win 10.  I use Chrome but I tested this in Firefox and Edge as well.  Does the same thing.

Comment: you should look into the hotkey configuraition in the “Server Configuration” Window of Synergy.

Comment: no hotkeys set on server.

Answer (score 1):

OK.  So I plugged the keyboard into a different USB port.  Wow.....just....wow.

Whoever thought that USB port could affect key mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but figured out why.
It is easy to fix, and kind of makes sense, too.

TLDR: You turned ***Function Lock*** on, so ***Turn it off***.

When function lock is turned on, on PC, it reverts to essentially the mac default for the fn keys. I.e. the f5 key controls the screen dim action, and so forth for all the other fn keys.

So, to fix, whilst holding down the function (fn) key, press the fn lock key, and hey presto...

Or you could keep it that way, and just access the fn keys by holding down the fn button.